# is there a way to have a python application run invisibly?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy application that I want to control over http with a simple gui. The problem is I don't want both the cherrypy window and the gui running at the same time. Is there a way I can make the cherrypy applications window visible?

Its being written for windows, which probably makes a difference

Comment: Windows?  or Linux?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pythonw.exe` rather than `python.exe` It will start without a console window.

If you're using py2exe, you need to change your setup file to not use a console

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script":"hello.py"}])
```